# Understanding control flow in Assembly

Tags: assembly, exponentiation

This function is not iterating properly. The result of it just squares the base regardless of the exponent. I have commented my thoughts on what I think is happening.

As an aside, is there an easy way I can debug assembly with breakpoints and stepping through? Potentially an IDE you recommend? Teach a man to fish they say...

Thank you for the help!

```
my_pow:
    movl $0, %eax
    movl %edi, %eax #result = base

    movl $2, %r9d #i = 2
    Loop:
        cmpl %r9d, %esi #if i <= exp
        mul %edi #multiply result*=base
        inc %r9d #i++
        jle Loop #if it was less than, do it again
    ret #if it was greater don't go to the label and return what is in %eax
```

Comment: The conditional jump should be immediately after the compare instruction.

Comment: gdb has a text ui or use ddd as a frontend. I believe vs code can also debug and there are others such as [edb-debugger](https://github.com/eteran/edb-debugger)

Comment: In general you should keep in mind that various instructions (not all, but more than just `cmp`) can change the flags.

Comment: Also make sure you know the requirements, in particular whether 0, 1 or a negative number is an allowed value for exponent.

Comment: `inc %r9d` / `jle` will jump based on FLAGS from the `inc`, since it writes the flags other than CF.  [`jle`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/jcc) is taken if `ZF=1 or SF≠ OF`.  Since R9D starts out positive, SF will be zero, and so will OF because `2+1` doesn't overflow when it produces `3`.  So the branch won't be taken, the loop body runs 1 time regardless of EDI, thus it's equivalent to `mov %edi, %eax` ; `imul %eax, %eax`.  You're not using the high half of the `mul` result (in EDX) so you should just use non-widening `imul` for efficiency and so you can use RDX for other stuff.